# Executing Javascript in a webhook endpoint

Tags: javascript, php, webhooks

This is my first attempt at creating a webhook endpoint, and I'm running into some issues. I'm sending a webhook from a [JotForm](http://www.jotform.com) to a php file on my server. The php is executing perfectly, but I also have some scripts in the file that reference an external script and run a function.

The end goal is to send the submission data from the jotform to our [Marketo](http://www.marketo.com/) CRM using Marketo's [API](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/websites/lead-tracking-munchkin-js/). However, the scripts in the endpoint don't seem to execute. This same script works perfectly if I set it up so the user actually hits a page with this script on it, but it doesn't work if I try to execute it through a webhook behind the scenes. Any idea what I'm missing? Here's the code in its entirety:

```
<?php
//Strips all slashes in an array
function stripslashes_deep($value){
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);
    return $value;
}
$result = stripslashes_deep($_REQUEST['rawRequest']);

//Convert json to php variable
$obj = json_decode($result, true);

//Initialize input variables
$theName = $obj['q1_name'];
$theEmail = $obj['q3_email'];
?>
<!----------------Marketo Munchkin API------------------------------>
<script src="http://munchkin.marketo.net/munchkin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  mktoMunchkin("OUR_MARKETO_ID");
  mktoMunchkinFunction(
   'associateLead',
   {
      Email: <?php echo "decodeURIComponent(\"" . rawurlencode($theEmail) . "\")" ?>,
      FirstName: <?php echo "decodeURIComponent(\"" . rawurlencode($theName) . "\")" ?>
   },
   '<?php echo hash('sha1', 'our-secret-key' . $theEmail); ?>'
);
</script>
<!---------------------------------------------------------------->
```

The "OUR_MARKETO_ID" and "our-secret-key" in the code contains our credentials.

Is there another way I should be executing the JS?

Answer (score 2):

*This same script works perfectly if I set it up so the user actually hits a page with this script on it, but it doesn't work if I try to execute it through a webhook behind the scenes.*

That seems to indicate that whatever is calling your webhook isn't evaluating the javascript at all. JotForm probably calls your webhook with a simple HTTP client or even a low-level Curl command, not a real browser that executes javascript.

I think you need to ditch javascript and use PHP. Doing all of this server-side is the only way to ensure that it runs regardless of what kind of client calls your webhook.

Looks like Marketo provides a SOAP api which you could use in PHP. Perhaps the `synchLead` method is what you need:

http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/soap/synclead/

Comment: Hm, yeah that would make sense that JotForm's call isn't even evaluating it. I'll have to take a look into using the SOAP api instead of the munchkin. Thanks